# OpenCV: Unable to run Canny edge detection in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, canny-operator

I have written a simple code to perform canny edge detection on a live stream. The code is as shown below,

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int lowThreshold=0;
int const max_lowThreshold = 100;
int kernel_size = 3;
int ratio = 3;

Mat img;
Mat display;

void CannyThreshold()
{
    cvtColor(img, display, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    // GaussianBlur(display,display,Size(7,7),3,3);
    GaussianBlur(display, display, Size(1, 1), 1,1);

    printf("%d\n",lowThreshold);

    Canny(display,display,lowThreshold,3);

    imshow("Canny",display);
}

int main()
{

    VideoCapture cap(0);

    namedWindow("Canny");
    createTrackbar("Min Threshold: ","Canny",&lowThreshold,max_lowThreshold);

    while(1)
    {
        cap.read(img);

        int ret = waitKey(1);

        CannyThreshold();

        if(ret == 'q')
            break;
    }

    cap.release();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following run-time error when I run the code. (I'm using OpenCV 4)

error: (-215:Assertion failed) ksize.width > 0 && ksize.width % 2 == 1 && ksize.height > 0 && ksize.height % 2 == 1 in function 'createGaussianKernels'

Any suggestions on how I can solve this error?

Comment: Yes. You are specifying a `kernel size` of `1`. That doesn't make sense. The kernel is the filter's discrete transfer function that you convolve the image with. It needs to be larger than that, it needs to have a central element and it needs to be odd. See: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1

Comment: Hey @stateMachine
I have changed the size to (3,3). I am still getting the same error.

 what(): OpenCV(4.5.5-dev) /home/deekshith/Desktop/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.dispatch.cpp:293: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ksize.width > 0 && ksize.width % 2 == 1 && ksize.height > 0 && ksize.height % 2 == 1 in function 'createGaussianKernels'

Answer (score 0):

The issue is GaussianBlur cant accept kernel size of 1. Correct it to 3x3 or 5x5 in  your code as follows

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    Mat frame;
    Mat image; // from cap to image
    Mat src_gray;

    Mat dst;
    Mat detected_edges;


    const String window_name = "Canny Edge Detector - VideoCapture";
    int lowThreshold = 10;
    const int max_lowThreshold = 100;
    const int ratio = 3;
    const int kernel_size = 3;

    int FPS;
    int frame_width, frame_height;

    int camNum = 0;
    cap.open(camNum);


    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {

        cout << "***Could not initialize capturing...***\n";
        cout << "Current parameter's value: \n";
        return -1;
    }


    FPS = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
    frame_width = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    frame_height = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    dst.create(frame_width, frame_height, CV_8UC3);

    //cout << CV_8UC3;

    while (true)
    {

        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            break;


        frame.copyTo(image);

        // Convert the image to grayscale
        cvtColor(image, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        //![reduce_noise]
        /// Reduce noise with a kernel 3x3
        blur(src_gray, detected_edges, Size(3, 3));
        //![reduce_noise]

        //![canny]
        /// Canny detector
        Canny(detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size);
        //![canny]

        /// Using Canny's output as a mask, we display our result
        //![fill]
        dst = Scalar::all(0);
        //![fill]

        //![copyto]
        image.copyTo(dst, detected_edges);
        //![copyto]


        //![display]
        imshow(window_name, dst);

        if (waitKey(1000 / FPS) >= 0)
            break;

    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey @balu,
I have made the necessary change. I still get the same error. 

what():  OpenCV(4.5.5-dev) /home/deekshith/Desktop/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.dispatch.cpp:293: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ksize.width > 0 && ksize.width % 2 == 1 && ksize.height > 0 && ksize.height % 2 == 1 in function 'createGaussianKernels'

Comment: check now. you are not updating all the params correctly

Comment: I just copy pasted your code. 
I still get the same error. I wonder if it's a bug with the latest release of OpenCV(4.5.5). Because if the program is executed multiple times, it does run occasionally, even with the code that I had written.

Comment: The error that you posted is compiling error. But now you say run time issue, I am not clear.

Comment: The error is a run-time error. 
Compilation is always successful. At times the program runs without any issues, and most of the times it doesn't run at all and throws the error. Note that the error is due to assert statement, and thus a run-time error.